# Finding confidence interval of observations

Tags: statistics

During year 2000 $N$ events occur. However, during year 2001 $M<N$ events occur. I am trying to find the 95% confidence interval of $M$ and $N$ in order to determine if 2001 really was that "different" compared to the year 2000.

First, I assume the events occuring in 2000 and 2001 are not correlated. But I feel like I am missing some information?

EDIT: I guess I am missing the standard deviation, which is merely $\sqrt{N}$ and$\sqrt{M}$, as I can assume they are distributed according to Poisson. So the confidence interval is merely $1.96\times \sqrt{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

From what you say, it does seem reasonable to assume that your observations are Poisson distributed. Based on $N$ events in 2000
one can use the confidence interval $N \pm 1.96\sqrt{N},$
with the *margin of error* you suggest. There is some theoretical
basis to use the adjusted interval $N+2 \pm 1.96\sqrt{N+1}$
instead. If this interval does not cover $M,$ then you might
be able to argue that $M$ is significantly less than $N$.

The difficulty is that you give no explicit information to
confirm that the two counts $M$ and $N$ are comparable. For
example if these are highway accidents on certain kinds of
roads, you would want to make sure that some of these roads
were not closed for repair in 2001, or that economic conditions
did not lead to less driving throughout the region in 2001. So you would have to be
careful in drawing meaningful conclusions from your confidence
interval.

*Reference:* For one more extensive discussion of this topic, look
at ([K. Krishnamoorthy
 & Meesook Lee (2012)](http://www.ucs.louisiana.edu/~kxk4695/Kris_Lee.pdf)).